# Selenium doesn't open URL but only opens browser

Tags: python, selenium

```
import shutil
from selenium import webdriver
import subprocess as sub

subprocess_obj = sub.Popen(['cmd', '/K', 'pip install selenium'])
subprocess_obj.wait()

video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
edge_path = None
edge_executables = ["msedge.exe","MicrosoftEdge.exe","MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe","MicrosoftEdgeBeta.exe"]

for edge in edge_executables:
    edge_path = shutil.which(edge)
    if edge_path:
        break

if edge_path:
    # specify the path to Edge driver
    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=edge_path)
    # Open Microsoft Edge
    driver.get(video_url)
else:
    print("Microsoft Edge is not found on the system.")
```

I tried to check compatible version and everything's fine (I guess?). Sorry if this code looks weird it was made by AI

Comment: # close the webdriver
driver.quit()

Comment: What error you've got?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this below `driver.get(video_url)`:

```
driver.maximize_window()
```